# Updating Custom NSWindow Appearance

Tags: swift, cocoa, swift3, nswindow

[image]

As shown above, I have a view controller (`NSViewController`) and a window controller (`NSWindowController`).  And I have a custom window (`NSWindow`) so that I can customize the look of the main window.  Specially, I just want to set a particular color to its background color.

```
class BasicBorderlessWindow: NSWindow {
    override init(contentRect: NSRect, styleMask style: NSWindowStyleMask, backing bufferingType: NSBackingStoreType, defer flag: Bool) {
        super.init(contentRect: contentRect, styleMask: style, backing: .buffered, defer: false)
        self.isOpaque = false
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor.green
    }
}
```

Now, the entire window is green.

What I want to know is a way of changing the color of entire window once the application starts up.  The subclassed window (BasicBorderlessWindow) is wired to the window controller.  So I can access it from the view controller.  I can create a function to set a new color so that I can call it from the view controller.  But I cannot refresh the window.  So how do I change window's background color and update it?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the window's background color from within the window controller. You don't need an NSWindow subclass for this at all.

`self.window?.backgroundColor = NSColor.blue`